# HTML: Fix footer at bottom of screen [using Sharepoint Designer 2013]

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I'm stuck with implementation of a sticky footer.

Please, note that I want the footer to be present always at **bottom of screen and not the Page**.

If it matters, I'm using sharepoint designer 2013 to code.

CSS I used:

```
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -30px;
overflow: visible;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 30px;
clear: both;
}
.footer {
 background: #0072C6;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
html,body  {
margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

The HTML structure:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<div class="footer">
<span>This is my SharePoint 2013 Footer</span></div>
</form>
```

The footer is not sticky. Please, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: use `position:fixed`

Comment: Hi Amit. I tried as given in answer by Neophyte. But, the thing is that footer is now actually overlapping the text present at bottom of the screen. Can you provide some help with that? here's a sample. https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/xzqqebdt/12/

Comment: you should use `height` for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try adding `position : fixed` , and `bottom : 0` to your `footer` tag, and it stays at the bottom of the page, checkout the link;

[Fixed Footer](https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/xzqqebdt/12/)

For beauty reasons, you can even add `width: 100%` to it, which enhances the GUI

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, footer is coming over the text. That is the bottom margin of -30px for wrapper didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/xzqqebdt/12/

Comment: footer is coming over the text? I don't completely understand that

Comment: Hi Neophyte. Please check the link. When I added a lot of text to the page. The footer is sticky at bottom but it's overlapping the text present at bottom. Basically, due to footer I'm not able to read last 1-2 lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

> Blockquote

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -30px;
}
.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto -30px;
 overflow: visible;
}
#form{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.footer, .push {
 height: 30px;
 clear: both;
}
.footer {
 background: #0072C6;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<div class="footer">
<span>This is my SharePoint 2013 Footer</span></div>
</form>
```

**

Comment: Hi. I guess position should be position:fixed and not absolute.